# How to manage time and resources efficiently?

Tags: resource-planning, human-resources, resources

I am new to resource management and I wanted to improve the time management of my team in handling tasks/projects. Do you have best practice to follow on giving out tasks or on planning the resources per each project? How can I improve the team as a whole?

Comment: Your question is extremely broad and subject for a few books. You might want to narrow it down to some problem you are trying to fix or ask more specific questions instead of just one big question.

Comment: As a start, think of people as people (and use that word when referencing them.) One key component of effective intellectual work is empowerment, and that goes along with respect. If your attitude towards people is looking down on them, you can't really expect them getting excellent results.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner The way I see it, the 'resource' of management is people's **time**.  The company I work at has 8 hours of my time to allocate as a resource. That's fine. They do not have *me* as a resource. That would violate anti-slavery laws.

Comment: By this notion, of course, the only thing you can do with resources is allocate/buy/sell/spend them. **You cannot talk to a resource**. A resource is not a thinking entity - it's a block of time. Or a printer. Or a room.
And by that notion, if you were to refer to an *actual person* as a 'resource', you *are* denying their existence as a thinking entity, which is just about the most disrespectful act possible. Hence, imo, the **'s time** part of this question is what makes it offensive, rather than the use of the word 'resource' itself.

Answer (score 2):

Alex! It's great that you are asking these questions, though I agree with both of your commenters. If your company is refusing to provide leadership training, two places to start are your local library--pick up several books to get different perspectives--and your local chapter of the Project Management Institute.

In general, management books and researchers are shifting the role of a supervisor from "control and direct" to "coach and support." That is, as Hans-Martin said, empower people. For example:

- Give them the list of items that need to be done, then let them decide who will do it and how. (Later, put them directly in contact with your "customers," whether those are inside or outside the company, and let them create that list.)
- If someone comes to you with a problem, ask them how they suggest to fix it. Give them advice, but let them make the choice, and don't criticize if their solution doesn't work out: They just learned a lesson better than if you gave them an order!
- If you have to criticize, do it in private; only give praise in public.
- And unless a fast decision must be made now, the best answers on average over time will be made by the collective intelligence of the team, if members feel safe to share their opinions with you and each other.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this one and hopefully I can improve on this role.